# Where are files I upload on my local parse Server?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, parse-server

I use a local version of Parse Server on my computer running on Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS. I often upload files using the API. I would like to have the location of theses files or at least their names in order to delete them.

I already read the documentation. Particulary, this section : https://docs.parseplatform.org/rest/guide/#uploading-files

It looks like if we don't have the name, we can't delete it with the API.

Here's the configuration of the server.

```
var parseServer = new ParseServer({
    databaseURI: "mongodb://localhost:27017/local",  
    cloud: __dirname + '/cloud/main.js',  
    appId: MY_APP_ID,  
    masterKey: MASTER_KEY,  
    serverURL: 'http://localhost:1337/parse',  
    publicServerURL: public_server
});
```

I expect to have at least the name of the files.

Comment: details of uploaded files depends on which implementation of file-storage is being used in your config for parse-server.   you may find this lib/module useful in after the fact list utils ... https://github.com/parse-server-modules/parse-files-utils

Answer (score 1):

Parse Server supports multiple [File Adapters](https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server/#configuring-file-adapters) and the location of your files depend on which file adapter you are using in your application.

Since you are not specifying a file storage adapter in your Parse Server configuration, you are using the default adapter, that is the GridFSBucketAdapter.

Therefore your files are stored in your MongoDB database. You can connect to your database and find your file names in your `files` connection.

You can find more information about MongoDB GridFS [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/gridfs/).